# dropdown menu inside of react bootstrap collapsible panel header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap.

I am using the collapsible panels from the library and want to know if there is a way I can add a dropdown menu to the panel header without it triggering the panel collapse event

this is the panel code I use:

```
<Panel
   header={<label htmlFor={ro.id}>{ro.slug}</label>}
   collapsible
   defaultExpanded={true}
   bsStyle={"primary"}
 >
   {storyList}
</Panel>
```

I essentially want to create an action menu within the panel header, but placing anything in there and clicking on it the new button always triggers the panel collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [Controlled PanelGroups](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-controlled) example, both `Panel`s and `PanelGroup`s have an `onSelect` prop you can plug into.

Comment: Sorry but being naive here I do not understand how those panels could solve my situation.

Comment: Ordinary panels keep the collapsed state internally and you don't have a callback for collapse events. If you use a controlled panel, you can keep collapsed state in your own component and you will have an onSelect handler, in which you can check for the clicked item. If the event target is the dropdown, you can choose not to change collapsed state of the panel.